# Replace all occurances of one string with different values in a list - Python

Tags: python, text-parsing

I am new to python programming. I have a list [alex,22,seattle] and a text file that contains

my name is ----. I am ----
I live in ----

I want some help to know how I can replace these '----' with each of the elements in the list in that order.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [reduce()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
>>> s = "my name is ----. I am ---- I live in ----"
>>> l = ['alex','22','seattle'] 
>>> reduce(lambda x, to: x.replace('----', to, 1), l, s)
'my name is alex. I am 22 I live in seattle'
```

Answer (score 0):

First that's not a valid list literal, the strings need quotes.

In this case the string formatting operator `%` is a good fit

```
>>> arr = ['alex', 22, 'seattle']
>>> template = 'my name is ----. I am ---- I live in ----'.replace('----', '%s')
>>> print template % tuple(arr)
my name is alex. I am 22 I live in seattle
```